What do CaGEL and CGEL stand for?
I saw some people use CaGEL and CGEL to refer to some English grammar books. What do they stand for?
Does CaGEL refer to The Cambridge Grammar of the English Language, by Huddleton et al?
How about CGEL?

CGEL is ambiguous. I've updated our FAQ on that.

@AndrewLeach This is not the best close. Scrolling down the list of acronyms and having to work out that this acronym is homophonous is superlatively confusing and actively makes things difficult for readers. In contrast, having a clear answer here on this page for this high-frequency problem, as Tim has realised in a community-minded way, is extra-specially helpful. Please reconsider and open  this, Andrew :)

@AndrewLeach — Were is this “FAQ” that you speak of?

@TinfoilHat Follow the link in the post notice.

@AndrewLeach — I was looking for a whole section called FAQ, but I see now that it’s just a tag.

@TinfoilHat Ah. I meant "I've updated our Frequently Asked Question on that". And of course, the "faq" tag does create a section. // Hmm. Can't do the usual [ ] notation for that tag as it links to the wrong place: [faq]

Two more reopen votes to go!

@Tim, have you voted to reopen your question yet?

Here's a faq tag link.

@Araucaria-Him Tim's meta question has been reopened for a few days now

Answers about abbreviations and related shorthand terminology can be found in the Community Wiki answer to: "List of common abbreviations and acronyms (NOAD, ESL, PIE...)" (and Conventions, Geographical and Historical Varieties).


CaGEL — The Cambridge Grammar of the English Language
CGEL — The Cambridge Grammar of the English Language or
CGEL — A Comprehensive Grammar of the English Language


That answer can be edited to update as necessary, so this Q&A can serve as a duplicate signpost to questions about abbreviations or jargon.

Someone might give a more useful answer than yours. Not time to dupe-close yet.
